# How To Use Vimeo Upload

Tags: ios, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I am trying to upload videos to a Vimeo Account through an iOS app written in Swift.  How can I incorporate the VimeoUpload SDK into my app?  Does it depend on VimeoNetworking or VIMNetworking?  Since these are not available as Cocoapods, what is the best way to include these libraries?

Comment: Hi i tried to implement uploading but its not giving uploading status and uploaded URL in call back, could you please share your uploading code ?

Answer (score 3):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol vimeodelagate;
@interface Vimeo_uploader : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

@property(weak) id<vimeodelagate> delegate;



+(id)SharedManger;
-(void)pass_data_header:(NSData *)videoData;
- (void)Give_title_to_video:(NSString *)VIdeo_id With_name:(NSString *)name ;


@end

@protocol vimeodelagate <NSObject>
-(void)vimeouploader_succes:(NSString *)link methodName:(NSString *)methodName;
-(void)vimeouploader_progress:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalByte;
-(void)vimeouploader_error:(NSError *)error methodName:(NSString *)methodName;

@end




#define  Aurtorizartion  @"bearer your token"
#define  accept  @"application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2"

#import "Vimeo_uploader.h"

@implementation Vimeo_uploader


+(id)SharedManger{

    static Vimeo_uploader *Vimeouploader = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncetoken;
        dispatch_once(&oncetoken, ^{
            Vimeouploader = [[self alloc] init];
        });
    }
    return Vimeouploader;
}

-(id)init{

    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)pass_data_header:(NSData *)videoData{

    NSString *tmpUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?type=streaming&redirect_url=&upgrade_to_1080=false"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];//change this according to your need.
    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &error];
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        [self call_for_ticket:[json valueForKey:@"upload_link_secure"] complet_url:[json valueForKey:@"complete_uri"] videoData:videoData];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE--->%@",json);
    }


}
- (void)call_for_ticket:(NSString *)upload_url complet_url:(NSString *)complet_uri videoData:(NSData *)videoData{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration;
    //configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5;
    //configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5;
    configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
   // configuration.networkServiceType = NSURLNetworkServiceTypeBackground;
    configuration.discretionary = NO;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                          delegate:self
                                                     delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:upload_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:0];
    [urlRequest setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [urlRequest setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *str_lenth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)videoData.length];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"str_lenth":str_lenth,
                           @"Content-Type":@"video/mp4"};
    NSData *postData12 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData12];
   // [urlRequest setHTTPBody:videoData];



    // You could try use uploadTaskWithRequest fromData
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *taskUpload = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromData:videoData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        if (!error && httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
             [self call_complete_uri:complet_uri];
        } else {
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ AND HTTPREST ERROR : %ld", error, (long)httpResp.statusCode);
        }
    }];
    [taskUpload resume];


}
-(void)call_complete_uri:(NSString *)complettion_url{


    NSString *str_url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com%@",complettion_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    //change this according to your need.

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
           if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 201) {
               NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[httpResponse allHeaderFields]];
               if (dict) {
                   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_succes:methodName:)]){
                     //  [self.delegate vimeouploader_succes:[dict valueForKey:@"Location"] methodName:@"vimeo"];
                       NSLog(@"sucesses");

                       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title"];
                       [self Give_title_to_video:[dict valueForKey:@"Location"] With_name:str];



                   }else{
                       if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                           [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
                   }
               }
           }else{
               //9
               if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                   [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
               NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
           }
    }];

}
- (void)Give_title_to_video:(NSString *)VIdeo_id With_name:(NSString *)name {

    NSString *tmpUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com%@",VIdeo_id];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PATCH"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];//change this according to your need.
    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &error];
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     NSString *str_description =  @"description";
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"name":name,
                           @"description":str_description,
                           @"review_link":@"false"
                           };

    NSData *postData12 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData12];

    if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"RESPONSE--->%@",json);

         [self.delegate vimeouploader_succes:[json valueForKey:@"link"] methodName:@"vimeo"];
    }else{
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
            [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
        //NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Give_title_to_video_error--->%@",error);
    }


}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {

    NSLog(@"didSendBodyData: %lld, totalBytesSent: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToSend: %lld", bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_progress:totalBytesExpectedToSend:)]){
        [self.delegate vimeouploader_progress:totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:totalBytesExpectedToSend];}
}



- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Task: %@ upload complete", task);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Task: %@ upload with error: %@", task, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Your code is working but title and description for video is not set. @Mahesh Joya

Answer (score -1):

I work for Vimeo.

VimeoUpload is in limbo for a few more weeks. We ran into a host of issues related to Objc <> Swift interoperability and iOS7 <> iOS8+ that prevented us from making VimeoUpload available as a Cocoapod.

We plan to do this work starting in late July 2016. Which means that by mid-August 2016 VimeoUpload should be available as a legit v1.0 available via Cocoapods.

In the interim you can include the library as a git submodule. Make sure to include `master` branch and not `v1.0` branch. And then set the submodule up as a "development pod". This will pull in a subspec from VIMNetworking.

Let me know if you have other questions, happy to help / trying to get v1.0 finished asap.

Comment: Does the VimeoUpload library work with UIImagePickerController (which compresses videos)?  I use the imagepicker controller to get the "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL." Then, I use PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs to get a PHAsset.  I then try to upload a video using the ExportOperation method explained on the README.  However, the video does not appear on my VimeoAccount.  I just see "Create <descriptor identifier>" in Xcode's logs, and I do not receive any error.

Comment: Hi i tried to implement uploading but its not giving uploading status and uploaded URL in call back, could you please share your uploading code ?

Comment: Hi, i want to upload video on vimeo. Is there any library for objective c. Please help me.